# some android package style value is empty

Tags: android

after i finish packing, open the resource.arsc file ,some style value is empty, is this normal?
[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1BWm.png)

when i use one theme of these, it crashed after running :
my code:

```
`<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" // use this theme , crashed
 />`
```

crashed:

```
`Error inflating class TextView Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4:     TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}`
```

is this normal? or how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because you are trying apply style `Body1` as theme. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes#versus):

> A style specifies attributes for a particular type of view...

> A theme defines a collection of named resources that can be referenced...

When you want to style look of view, you have to use `style` attribute, not `android:theme`. Your code should look like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
/>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have another question, why some style value is empty in pkg (the despcription is in the picture I uploaded named "enter image" at the beginning of the question).

Comment: I am not 100% sure but i think it's for naming consistency of styles so programmer can access styles more easily. In `values.xml` you can see `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1` has parent style `Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1` which holds attributes (and has 2 implementations based on OS versions).